# (-2:Unspecified error) Can't create layer "FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV3/Conv/hard_swish/add" of type "AddV2" in function 'getLayerInstance'

Tags: python, opencv

I am facing a problem in `classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img,confThreshold=float0.5)`
How to fix it?Please help.

I am trying to run a very simple OpenCV script:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("index.jpeg")

classNames= []
classFile = 'coco.names'
with open(classFile,'rt') as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')

configPath = "ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt"
weightsPath = "frozen_inference_graph.pb"

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath,configPath)
net.setInputSize(320,320)
net.setInputScale(1.0/ 127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)

classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img,confThreshold=0.5) #line 19
print(classIds,bbox)


cv2.imshow("Output",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[Picture of full error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoNiE.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think upgrading your opencv version up to 4.5 and above, is needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).